# How can a Python context manager try to execute code?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, yield, contextmanager

I'm trying to write a small context manager that'll try to execute some code repeatedly until the code works or until a specified number of tries has been made. I have attempted to write this but am encountering a difficulty with having the context manager handle problems when yielding:

```
Exception RuntimeError: 'generator ignored GeneratorExit'
```

How should I code this?

```
import contextlib
import random

def main():

    with nolube():
        print(1 / random.randint(0, 1))

@contextlib.contextmanager
def nolube(
    tries = None # None: try indefinitely
    ):
    """
    Create a context for trying something repeatedly.
    """
    tries_done = 0
    rekt = True
    if tries is None:
        while rekt is True:
            try:
                yield
                rekt = False
            except:
                tries_done += 1
                pass
    else:
        while rekt is True and tries_done <= tries:
            try:
                yield
                rekt = False
            except:
                tries_done += 1
                pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@contextlib.contextmanager` has a very clear contract; it'll only be resumed **once**. It can't be used to re-run code.

In fact, you can't use a context manager to control repetitions *at all*. You need a loop here, not a context manager. A context manager doesn't control the block, it is only informed when entering and exiting.

Use the [`tenacity` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tenacity)<sup>*</sup> instead; it provides a decorator. The decorator [wraps a function in a `while True` loop](https://github.com/jd/tenacity/blob/5dd4c194a3a3a96cb61638e152f7babd472c2d07/tenacity/__init__.py#L311-L326) that'll re-run the function for you.

You'd apply it to your case by moving the `print()` statement into a function, decorated with `@retry`, then calling that function:

```
import random
from tenacity import retry

@retry
def foo():
    print(1 / random.randint(0, 1))

def main():
    foo()
```

---

<sup>*</sup> This answer originally recommended the [`retrying` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying) but this was [forked into a new package with updated API](https://github.com/rholder/retrying/issues/65) when that project fell dormant.

Comment: The `retrying` package hasn't been updated for a while. But there's a fork called [tenacity](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tenacity) which is being maintained.

Comment: @TimB: thanks for the heads-up, I've edited the answer to recommend tenacity instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. A context manager in Python is simply a protocol which:

1. Calls `__enter__`
2. Executes one or more statements
3. Calls `__exit__`

Point 3. is guaranteed to happen, which makes it great for handling resource releasing, etc. But the important point here is point 2.: the context manager will run the code *within* the context, then process 3. By that point, the wrapped code is gone, forgotten and unreachable forever, so you can't 'call it again'. `contextlib` offers a nice API for defining your context manager simply by doing it as a function:

```
@contextmanager
def ctxt():
    # 1: __enter__ code
    yield
    # 3: __exit__ code
```

And the documentation clearly [specifies](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

> The function being decorated must return a generator-iterator when called. This iterator must yield exactly one value, which will be bound to the targets in the with statement’s as clause, if any.

So the previous point remains.

What you *can* do to call something repeteadly is to put it in a function, and decorate *that* function with your 'repeat until success' logic:

```
def dec(f):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                pass
    return decorated
```

But this is totally unrelated to context managers.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: you can't really do this with context manager in Python.

We can only `yield` once in a context manager, so it doesn't make sense to use `yield` inside a `while` loop. This is different from the `yield` used in `Ruby` `block`s.

And we don't have access to the body of code either, for example, we don't automatically get something like a `function` that we can reuse.

So, no, if you do want to implement a reusable `retry` logic, use a function instead.

```
def retry(func, n_times=None):
    i = 1
    while True:
       try:
           return func()
       except Exception:
           i += 1
           if n_times and i >= n_times:
               raise
```