# How can a yield be used with a lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, yield, contextmanager

I'm trying to write a context manager or something similar that can be used to repeatedly try some code. There are many, many things to be tried in the actual project, so I don't want to write a separate function for each thing, and I'm also dealing with a big object in the main scope that can't easily be passed to functions etc., so I'm trying to have some simple line of code that I can pop in front of something to try repeatedly in the main scope.

One way of trying something repeatedly without using a typical function definition is to use a lambda with the `retrying` module's `retry` function:

```
test = retrying.retry(lambda: print(1 / random.randint(0, 1)))
test()
```

What I'd like is something more minimal to write, something a bit like this:

```
with nolube():
    print(1 / random.randint(0, 1))
```

I've tried to code this in a context manager, but have run into difficulty (invalid syntax) when mixing lambda with yield in a way that probably illustrates a lack of understanding of yields. Is there some (perhaps hacky) way of approaching this?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import contextlib
import random
import retrying

def main():

    with nolube():
        print(1 / random.randint(0, 1))

@contextlib.contextmanager
def nolube(
    tries = None # None: try indefinitely
    ):
    """
    Create a context for trying something repeatedly.
    """
    tries_done = 0
    rekt = True
    if tries is None:
        while rekt is True:
            try:
                code = lambda: yield
                code()
                rekt = False
            except:
                tries_done += 1
                pass
    else:
        while rekt is True and tries_done <= tries:
            try:
                code = lambda: yield
                code()
                rekt = False
            except:
                tries_done += 1
                pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the syntax error:

```
    code = lambda: yield
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's the problem using the `retrying` module instead:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import contextlib
import random
import retrying

def main():

    with nolube():
        print(1 / random.randint(0, 1))

@contextlib.contextmanager
def nolube():
    """
    Create a context for trying something repeatedly.
    """
    code = retrying.retry(lambda: yield)
    code()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Where do you get invalid syntax error?  What are you expecting to accomplish with `code = lambda: yield` and then calling `code()` right away?

Comment: @BrenBarn Hey, thanks for taking a look. I've added the syntax error. I'm trying to get the code that's "passed" to the context manager to execute at that point.

Comment: You want `with nolube()` to be the equivalent of a `for` loop, is that correct? You want `print(1 / random.randint(0, 1))` to execute several times?

Comment: A with-statement is no loop. You cannot repeat the with-block with a content  manager.

Comment: You can't use a context manager to repeat a block of code.  Your context manager only gets to run before the block and after it.  There is no block that is "passed" to the context manager.

Comment: You can get rid of the syntax error by doing `lambda: (yield)`, but that won't help you achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Robᵩ No, I'm trying to write something that can be written easily in the main scope that'll execute some code until it works (in this example, the pseudorandom numbers created can break the division sometimes).

Comment: @BrenBarn Ok, so is there a different way of looking at this problem? Is there some single-liner way of indicating that some code should be repeated until it works without that code losing its view of the main scope?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a Python context manager try to execute code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740887/how-can-a-python-context-manager-try-to-execute-code)

Comment: @d3pd: No, there isn't.